# Why this ANSI Art doesn't render properly on Linux terminal

Tags: terminal, character-encoding, ansi

I'm trying to investigate why my library don't render this ANSI art properly:

[image: ANSI art of a meat eating flower]

I though that the problem is in my ANSI escape processing but it seems that it's the same in real terminal (tested in XFce terminal).

[image: terminal with ANSI art]

I have no idea how to debug this, the file is in CP437 encoding and can be found at [16colo.rs website](https://16colo.rs/pack/blocktr0nics30302020/67_Calendar_2020_06_June.ans). I've converted it to UTF8 (also meta tags, that show number of characters per line, are removed) and the file can be found here: https://jcubic.pl/text.ans the terminal need to have 80 columns otherwise it will not display properly.

I'm fine with answer why it's broken, but it would also be nice to know how to fix it and display properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rendering issue is caused by null bytes, which are shown as spaces by ANSI editors (and under DOS, presumably, although I haven’t checked).

To fix this:

```
tr '\0' ' ' < 67_Calendar_2020_06_June.ans | iconv -f CP437 -t UTF8
```