# Missing one character in ANSI art on Linux

Tags: terminal, character-encoding, ansi

This continuation of [Why this ANSI Art doesn't render properly on Linux terminal](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/611326/1806)

I have one more issue with ANSI art on Linux terminal that renders properly in ANSI art editor (like [PabloDraw](http://picoe.ca/products/pablodraw/)).

The file is another calendar page but this time for May https://16colo.rs/pack/blocktr0nics30302020/67_Calendar_2020_05_May.ans

[image: ANSI art of a Bee on a flower]

This how it look like on terminal:

[image: Terminal window with ANSI art]

The end is SAUCE meta tags that should be stripped of when rendering. But the issue is the left top have gradient and last two elements are on right side on Linux Terminal. The other thing is that the missing last character (it show as � but that's begnining of SAUCE record and marker that this is end of the artwork).

The same is with my JavaScript that I'm trying to fix https://codepen.io/jcubic/pen/pxdxmN?editors=0110 (enter `cat 67_Calendar_2020_05_May.ans` to render that ANSI art).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There’s a star on the fifth line, 0x0F in CP-437; that’s left as-is in UTF-8, as it should be, but in the terminal it’s a non-printable character (Ctrl-Q) so it disappears in the output. This shifts the rest of the file left by one character, producing all the other effects you mention.  It is not a printable graphic; it is a C0 control code.  Replace it with U+263C (☼) and things should look better.

Comment: I've found that parser I wa using found control character `0x0F` If I covert that to star it works as it should.

Comment: The U+001A should be stripped by whatever is removing your SAUCE information.  The problem here is that you have a file with embedded metadata, that is assuming MS/PC/DR-DOS code pages and `ANSI.SYS` CON: device processing, and the semantics of the `TYPE` command in Microsoft's/IBM's `COMMAND` command processor, and you are just blatting it out to a terminal emulator and expecting things to work.  You have to properly post-process it to _properly_ remove the metadata, and translate the use of C0 and C1 characters for graphics, which is a DOS-ism.

Comment: @JdeBP I've thought that it was in the middle of the file because there was other stuff just after but it seems I was mistaken maybe SAUCE parsing code calculated in wrong way lenght of the file and it didn't stripped of the 0x1A character.